# Access ContentPresenter children for Visualstate animation

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm using the following `GridView` and have an `ItemTemplate` with 3 Elements inside.

Now what i would like to do, is to animate the MyTextBlock opacity on `PointerOver` from the GridViewItem.

```
<GridView x:Name="MyList" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemContainerStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                <RowDefinition Height="3" />
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Url}" />
            <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" IsIndeterminate="True" />
            <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" Opacity="0" Text="Test" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The `ItemContainerStyle` is like this. Problem is, i can't access `MyTextBlock` with `Storyboard.TargetName="MyTextBlock"` from here since it's inside the `ContentPresenter`. 
How can i do a visualstate animation of an element inside the `ContentPresenter`?

```
<Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Key="GridViewItemContainerStyle">
       ...
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentBorder" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">                          
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BorderRectangle" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" Opacity="0" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

---

**Edit:** 
I tried using the following `TargetProperty`, but it's just setting the opacity of the whole `ContentPresenter`
and not just `TextBlock` inside of it.

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)" Duration="0" To="1" />
```

Comment: Did you try setting your storyboard inside Grid Control of DataTemplate?

Comment: When i put the storyboard inside the the Grid.Resource i cannot access it from codebehind to start it. When i put it into the Page.Resource i get a "No installed components were detected" COMException. I guess because it doesn't know which one to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is, i can't access MyTextBlock with Storyboard.TargetName="MyTextBlock" from here since it's inside the ContentPresenter. How can i do a visualstate animation of an element inside the ContentPresenter?

You can add two `visualstates` inside DataTemplate(`PointerEntered` and `PointerExited`):

```
<GridView x:Name="MyList" Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemContainerStyle}" >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited" PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerEntered">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerExited">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="3" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Url}" />
                    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" IsIndeterminate="True" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Name="MyTextBlock" Opacity="0" Text="Test" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

And using the following codes in `Grid.PointerEntered` and `Grid.PointerExited` events to get the `storyboard` start:

```
private void Grid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = sender as Grid;
    var visualStateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(grid);
    var visualStateGroup = visualStateGroups[0];
    visualStateGroup.States[1].Storyboard.Begin();
}

private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = sender as Grid;
    var visualStateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(grid);
    var visualStateGroup = visualStateGroups[0];
    visualStateGroup.States[0].Storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: I accepted this solution because it solves my problem. But how would you do this, if the contentPresenter is not using the full size of the gridViewItem, because let's say there is a Margin around it?

Answer (score 0):

`DataTemplate` can come from anywhere (App Resource, Window Resource, Local Resource, Code), so it uses its own `NameScope`.

You are unable to use `MyTextBlock` because of `Namescope` issues. So, best would be to define `VisualStates` as part of `DataTemplate` itself.